# Is it possible to elevate only an AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, uac, appdomain

Is there a way to generate a from a un-elevated program a new AppDomain that is elevated (showing a UAC prompt of course)?

I know you can do it using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) by doing

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

however I would like it if the main application was terminated the 2nd elevated portion was terminated too, and the only way I see potentially how do do that is if both the un-elevated portion and the elevated portion where two AppDomains in the same process.

Is it possible to elevate a AppDomain or must I start a totally separate process?

The program I am writing is going to be in .NET 2.0 for maximum compatability, but if there are things in 3.0 or 3.5 that would be useful I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 0):

No. Elevation is a property of a process, so 2 AppDomains can't have different elevations within the same process.